# .NET Core 3 Azure Function ILogger - correct use?

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

I have an Azure function. In my startup.cs I have

```
builder.Services.AddLogging();
```

In my function:

```
public void MyFunction(blah blah, ILogger log) {
    // this works fine, Hello world appears in the function output
    log.LogInformation("Hello world");
}
```

However if I try to inject ILogger log into a class library via the ctor I get a null.
So instead I inject ILogger with the ClassName and this appears to work fine, e.g.

```
public class MyClass() {
    private readonly ILogger<MyClass> _log;
    public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> log) {
       _log=log;
    }

    public void MyMethod() {
        // this logs, but it doesn't log to the azure function output
        _log.LogInformation("Inside a class library");
    }
}
```

My question is though, any log messages from the class, don't appear in the logging output for the function. What do I need to add to make it do this?

Comment: Do you have defined default log level in host.json and `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` set as application settings in your function app? Check [this](https://github.com/amigup/CleanArchitecture-For-AzureFunctionV3/tree/master/CleanArchitecture.Functions) working repo for additional configuration

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding a `logging` section to your `host.json` file:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "MySolutionName": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Replace `MySolutionName` with the full name of your solution. This should enable logging at a `logLevel` of `Information` and above.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that tomorrow, I already had this but with the wrong solution name because I had changed the solution name after I created it. Fingers crossed this is it!

Comment: No that hasn't fixed it, my app is still the same. _log.LogWarning("Test"); doesn't work if its in a class library. Thats injecting ILogger<ClassName> log;